# What types of device broadcast/cause interference on the 1.6GHz spectrum range

Tags: electrical-engineering

Other than networking devices, what domestic or domestic or commercial equipment could generate seemingly random interference on the 1.6 GHz range?

Either by design or through a malfunction.

What naturally occurring phenomena might cause such interference, either directly or through attenuation.

Context: interference with wireless device on this frequency - detectable on a handheld spectrum analyser - even when all known wireless devices are switched off.

Comment: Country matters. Look up what that band is assigned to by your regulatory agency.

Comment: And if it's imported from another country?

Comment: No, the country you are in. Because if you want to know what's broadcasting in that band you need to know what your country assigned as its usage.

Comment: `through a malfunction` ... the list of `what it could not possibly be` is probably shorter

Comment: this looks like an XY question ... exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ jsotola locate the source of the iterance by narrowing down possibly sources.

Comment: Microwave ovens and mobile phone network polling